# How to integrate way2sms in php?

Tags: php, curl, way2sms

I would like to integrate way2sms api in php code.
here my sample code , its error free but no message is sending . friends please help me where i have did mistake ? what do i need to change ?

sms.php

```
<?php
    $uid='9876543210';//10 digit mobile number
    $pwd='password';
    $phone='9876543210';
    $msg='from way 2 sms master ' ;

    include ('way2sms-api.php');
    $res= sendWay2SMS ( $uid , $pwd , $phone , $msg);
```

way2sms-api.php

```
<?php
    function sendWay2SMS($uid, $pwd, $phone, $msg) {
        $timeout = 30;
        $result = array();
        $uid = urlencode($uid);
        $pwd = urlencode($pwd);
        $autobalancer = rand(1, 8);

        $curl = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, "http://site".$autobalancer.".way2sms.com/Login1.action");
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "username=".$uid."&password=".$pwd."&button=Login");
        //curl_setopt($curl , CURLOPT_PROXY , '144.16.192.218:8080' );
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION, 1);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, "cookie_way2sms");
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS, 20);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.0; en-US; rv:1.9.0.5) Gecko/2008120122 Firefox/3.0.5");
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $timeout);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_REFERER, "http://site".$autobalancer.".way2sms.com/");

        $text = curl_exec($curl);

        // Check if any error occured
        if (curl_errno($curl)) return "access error : ". curl_error($curl);

        // Check for proper login
        $pos = stripos(curl_getinfo($curl, CURLINFO_EFFECTIVE_URL), "Main.action");
        if ($pos === "FALSE" || $pos == 0 || $pos == "") return "invalid login";
        if (trim($msg) == "" || strlen($msg) == 0) return "invalid message";

        $msg = urlencode(substr($msg, 0, 160));
        $pharr = explode(",", $phone);
        $refurl = curl_getinfo($curl, CURLINFO_EFFECTIVE_URL);

        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_REFERER, $refurl);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, "http://site".$autobalancer.".way2sms.com/jsp/InstantSMS.jsp");
        $text = curl_exec($curl);

        preg_match_all('/<input[\s]*type="hidden"[\s]*name="Action"[\s]*id="Action"[\s]*value="?([^>]*)?"/si', $text, $match);
        $action = $match[1][0]; // get custid from the form fro the Action field in the post form

        foreach ($pharr as $p) {
            if (strlen($p) != 10 || !is_numeric($p) || strpos($p, ".") != false) {
                $result[] = array('phone' => $p, 'msg' => urldecode($msg), 'result' => "invalid number");
                continue;
            }

            $p = urlencode($p);

            // Send SMS
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://site'.$autobalancer.'.way2sms.com/quicksms.action');
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_REFERER, curl_getinfo($curl, CURLINFO_EFFECTIVE_URL));
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "HiddenAction=instantsms&bulidgpwd=*******&bulidguid=username&catnamedis=Birthday&chkall=on&gpwd1=*******&guid1=username&ypwd1=*******&yuid1=username&Action=".$action."&MobNo=".$p."&textArea=".$msg);

            $contents = curl_exec($curl);

            //Check Message Status
            //preg_match_all('/<span class="style1">?([^>]*)?<\/span>/si', $contents, $match);
            //$out=str_replace("&nbsp;","",$match[1][0]);
            $pos = strpos($contents, 'Message has been submitted successfully');
            $res = ($pos !== false) ? true : false;
            $result[] = array('phone' => $p, 'msg' => urldecode($msg), 'result' => $res);

        }

        //echo $text;

        // Logout
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, "http://site".$autobalancer.".way2sms.com/LogOut");
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_REFERER, $refurl);
        $text = curl_exec($curl);
        curl_close($curl);
        return $result;
    }
```

Comment: Did you actually replace the configuration values with the credentials the API maintainers provided you? What's the response text of the API? Just because your code doesn't give any errors, doesn't mean the API doesn't either.

Comment: yes i replaced .... but i don't know what to do with this line . curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,
      "HiddenAction=instantsms&bulidgpwd=*******&bulidguid=username&catnamedis=Birthday&chkall=on&gpwd1=*******&guid1=username&ypwd1=*******&yuid1=username&Action=".
      $action."&MobNo=".$p."&textArea=".$msg);